# How can I show my own Control in Avalonia

Tags: avalonia

in my code, I create a class MyButon and it inherit button

```
`public class MyButon : Button`
```

but it can not show in UserContorl

`<StackPanel> <control2:MyButon  Background="Red" Width="100" Height="50"/> <Button Content="123" Background="Red" Width="100" Height="50"  /> </StackPanel>`

so what can i do to settle this Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not have an associated `.xaml` file the loader doesn't know which view to use. You can fix that by implementing `StyleKey` property from the `IStyleable` interface in your class. It will make your control use the `Button` style.

```
Type IStyleable.StyleKey => typeof(Button);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Avalonia 11+, IStyleable has been marked as obsolete.  The new way to do this would be to put the following line inside your control class.

```
protected override Type StyleKeyOverride => typeof(Button);
```